# Choose matrix columns based on constraint on whole matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, octave

I am trying to construct a Hsiao parity matrix.  I want to construct a matrix with the properties stated in [Hsiao's paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~culler/cs252-s02/papers/hsiao70.pdf).  One of the steps to construct the matrix is

> From `nchoosek(r,3)` weight-`3` columns possible, select `k` columns.  Here, `r` and `k` are the number of check bits and data bits, respectively.  Also, this is done when the following is done (`nchoosek(r,3) >= k`, where `k == No. of data bits`).

In Matlab, I was able to get the matrix containing all combinations of weight-`3` columns using the following:

```
unique(perms([1,1,1,0,0,0]) # For a (22,16) code.
```

However, another step to optimize the logic depth is to ensure that when we choose the `k` columns, we should choose them such that the number of ones in every row is the same are close to the average (which translates to number of XOR operations that we have to perform per check bit).

Now, is there a way to specify constraints on choosing columns from a matrix on the whole matrix?  That is, does Octave/Matlab have any way to specify conditions like

> Select `k` columns such that (number of `ones(rowi)` is approximately equal to number of `ones(rowj)` where `i != j`)  ## Or I can specify a tolerable difference.

**Example**

Say, I have the following five columns:

```
(1 0 0), (1 0 1), (0 1 0), (1 1 0), (0 0 1)
```

and say I have to choose `k=2` columns, I might choose `(1 1 0)` and `(0 0 1)` (I could have also chosen `(1 0 1)` and `(0 1 0)`, but not `(1 0 0)` and `(1 0 1)`) as it satisfies the above mentioned condition.

EDIT 1: I do know that I can do something like akin to what is done in Peter Norvig's [Sudoku solver page](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).  Just hoping that there might be an idiomatic way to do this in Octave/Matlab or exploit any property that I may be missing.  Else, I will have to roll up my sleeves and start implementing the constraint propagation engine myself.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: There, updated it with a small example.